# App possess a virus, suggest uninstalling the app

Tags: android, uninstallation, virus

i m developing an android app, while install this app on Android 8.0, a virus message will shown there, i am trying many things, also trying by remove all permissions from manifest, Any help would appreciated,

Virus message "App possess a virus, suggest uninstalling the app"

[image]

Comment: This message might appear because it wasn't installed from the google play store. It is possible that Android shows this message for any app installed from another source (I'm assuming you installed the app from an apk or through adb).

Comment: yes, i am installing the release apk from google drive, but why this message shown for this app only, for another non-play store apps, this message not come,  

  i have also disable play-protect from play store

Comment: Okay, then I guess this is just a warning from Android to the user that they are installing an app from an unknown source. It has nothing to do with your app specifically.

Comment: yes it doesn't affect my app's functionality, but the user may uninstall the app without using it when this harmful message come.